# Missing argument inside a form of django app

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I am trying to access a user product list inside the form of my django app.

The user information should be the input options of a form from the app.

What argument should I pass in my list_prod bellow?

I am receiving the following error message: TypeError: list_prod() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

Please Help!

Form

```
class ProductsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       super(ProductsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def list_prod(self):
        user_name = (self.request).user.username
        u = User.objects.get(username=user_name).accesslevel.prod.split(',')
        v=(('---------','---------'),)
        for l in u:
           v=v+((l.lstrip(),l.lstrip()),)
    model = Factory
    Lists = forms.ChoiceField(choices=list_prod())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it like that. `list_prod` is an instance method and must be called with an instance, but Lists is a class-level variable. You need to do this inside `__init__`:

```
class ProductsForm(forms.Form):
    Lists = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
       super(ProductsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.fields['Lists'].choices = self.list_prod()
```

Note also that as ProductsForm is a plain form, not a ModelForm, your `model` declaration does nothing. And, even if you did change it to be a ModelForm, that declaration needs to be inside an inner Meta class.

Note *also* that much of the logic inside `list_prod` is pointless; `request.user` is *already* a User, there is no need to fetch it again by querying User.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for the answer.. What should I put instead of u = User.objects.get(username=user_name).accesslevel.prod.split(',')?

Comment: Why not just `request.user.accesslevel...`?